Proving the identity $|x+|y|| + |x-|y||$
So I was playing around with the following function:
$f(x,y) = |x+|y||+|x-|y||$
It seems that the following identity is true for all pairs $(x,y)$:
$|x+|y||+|x-|y||=|x+y|+|x-y|$
The proof should be fairly trivial with a proof by cases, but I was wondering if:

Is this a known identity? It seems fairly trivial and I was wondering how old this fact is
Are there other known proofs for this other than the proof by exhaustion?

I have not found much about this online. It is kind of like the idempotence identity of the absolute value.

Notice that if you change the sign of $y$ both sides of the identity are invariant, so you can assume that $y \ge 0$, which makes the identity trivial.

"proof by exhaustion"? Only two cases ($y<0$, $y \ge 0$) to consider, why bother not doing it?

I was just curious if there was some other way to come up with the fact. Also, if there was a generalization of it to more than 2 variables. Just found it an interesting fact.

It's not true for complex numbers. But for real numbers it follows immediately from the tautology $y =\pm |y|$ (or equivalently $|y| = \pm y$).  I don't think there is any proof other than exhaustion as it is only true with $y = \pm |y|$ and will be false otherwise so any proof would have to use $y = \pm |y|$ and ... that's exhaustion.  It doesn't have a name as it's pretty trivial and obvious.

Just for thoroughness.  Consider $x = 1$ and $y=i$ then $|x+|y|| + |x-|y||=|1+|i|| + |1-|i|| = |1+1| + |1-1| = |2| + |0| = 2$. but $|x+y| + |x-y| = |1+i| + |1-i| = \sqrt{1^2 + 1^2} + \sqrt{1^2+1^2} = 2\sqrt 2 \ne 2$.  So it is not true for complex numbers.

I would just say: one of $y$ and $-y$ is $|y|$; the other is $-|y|$. So one of the terms is $|x+y|$. The other is $|x-y|$.

Here is a proof that may be equivalent to what you're calling "exhaustion" although I cannot say I, personally, am exhausted by it:
Recall that for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have: $|y| = \max\{y, -y\}$. Therefore,
$$|x + |y|| + |x - |y||  =|x + \max\{y, -y\}| + |x - \max\{y, -y\}|$$
Now, which is bigger: $y$ or $-y$? Either way, one of them appears with a plus before it and the other appears with minus before it, so we get both possibilities. Since addition is commutative, we can write this as:
$$|x + y| + |x - y|$$
as desired, and the same equality would hold if the central operation were another commutative one, e.g., multiplication.

it's sort of the same as "exhaustion": no matter y is positive or negative, it ends up with the same expression as RHS: one +y while the other -y

@GBmath I agree! I hope that (perhaps...) conceiving of an absolute value in terms of max might be a worthwhile contribution for the OP's wonders. I have more thoughts on absolute values and their interpretations on MESE (from 5 years ago).

For every $x,y\in\Bbb R$, $$g(x,y):=|x+y|+|x-y|\ge0$$
and
$$\left(g(x,y)\right)^2=2(x^2+y^2+|x^2-y^2|)=\left(g(x,|y|)\right)^2.$$
Therefore,
$$g(x,y)=g(x,|y|).$$
